# How to pass new position of marker into a function

Tags: angular, google-api, ionic2, google-maps-markers

in fallowing code I want to pass dragged marker `LatLng` into a function to get address but it is not working

```
public LastLat : any; 
public LastLng : any;
```

.
.
.

```
lastLatLng(marker){
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() { 
  this.LastLat= marker.position.lat();
  this.LastLng= marker.position.lng();
  });

console.log(this.LastLat,this.LastLng);

      this.Getaddress(this.LastLat,this.LastLng);

}

Getaddress(LastLat, LastLng){
this.http.get('http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat='+LastLat+ '&lon='+LastLng + '&zoom=18&addressdetails=1')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data.display_name;
        console.log(this.data);
});
}
```

when running it says LastLat, LastLng undefined. Getaddress fails because  `this.LastLat,this.LastLng` has no data also console.log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to move call to GetAddress into your event listener:

```
lastLatLng(marker){
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', () => { 
        this.LastLat= marker.position.lat();
        this.LastLng= marker.position.lng();
        console.log(this.LastLat,this.LastLng);
        this.Getaddress(this.LastLat,this.LastLng);
    });
}
```

Comment: I've already tried but shows error: `Runtime Error
this.Getaddress is not a function`

Comment: Correct. When in event handler the 'this' does not point to your component, this is why it fails. You should use lambda to preserve the 'this' instead of plain function. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that works fine, could you please give me guide how to write functions to return or manipulate public variables.